# Is it possible to do HTML scraping , data mining through Python?

Tags: python, screen-scraping, data-mining

Can I gather intelligent data , HTML scraping using python? I have no knowledge of it , so I would like to get some idea.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python and data mining](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321749/python-and-data-mining)

Answer (score 3):

Look at the module scrapy:

http://scrapy.org/

Answer (score 3):

You certainly can - I developed [this library](http://code.google.com/p/webscraping/) in Python for my web scraping work.

A good parsing library is [lxml](http://lxml.de/).

If you are new to Python you may want to work through [this ebook](http://diveintopython.net/toc/index.html) first.

Comment: The Links Are Dead .

Comment: @TilakMadichetti No they are not.

Comment: oops sorry ! there was a problem with my network that time . My bad :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using urllib2 and Beautiful Soup.

urllib2 is useful for requesting URLs programmatically. It's part of the standard library: http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2

Beautiful Soup is good for mining HTML/XML and can be found here: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/BeautifulSoup

Answer (score 0):

You may also use htql library at: http://htql.net.